# Regex for matching any occurrence of ABC following XYZ anywhere in the string 

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to write a regular expression which would match any occurrence of ABC following XYZ anywhere in the string :

Ex. text - "Some ABC text followed by XYZ followed by multiple ABC, more ABC, more ABC"

i.e., the regex should match three ABC's coming after XYZ.

Any clues?

Comment: What should it capture in the sample text? `followed by multiple ABC, more ABC, more ABC` or each individual `ABC`?

Comment: it should capture all the ABC's

Comment: Is the point to count the occurances?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take an iterative approach:

```
s = "Some ABC text followed by XYZ followed by multiple ABC, more ABC, more ABC"

pattern = re.compile(r'(?<=XYZ)(.*?)ABC')
while pattern.search(s):
   s = pattern.sub(r'\1REPLACED', s)

print s
```

Output:

> Some ABC text followed by XYZ followed by multiple REPLACED, more
>   REPLACED, more REPLACED

Comment: @HansThen done. (i don't have enough reputation for upvote though)

Answer (score 1):

Just match the literal `XYZ` and group on the repeated `ABC`:

```
r'XYZ((?:ABC)+)'
```

The `(?:ABC)+` pattern matches a set of literal characters at least once, and the whole group is preceded by a literal XYZ.

This is quite basic regular expression 101, you should read a good [tutorial on regular expression matching](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html) to get started.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this? `r"(?<=XYZ)((?:ABC)+)"`. This will match only the occurrences of `ABC` when they follow `XYZ`, but will not include `XYZ` itself.

**EDIT**

Looks like I misunderstood OP's original question. The easiest way to do this would be to first find the string `XYZ`. Save the starting position of `XYZ`. Use the starting position as extra argument to `p.finditer(string, startpos)`. Please note that this will only work with compiled regular expressions, so you need to compile your pattern first.

The pattern you need is simply `r"(ABC)"`.

Alternatively, you can use `p.sub()`, which will also do the substitution, but for this to work on only a part of the string, you will need to create a substring first. `p.sub()` does not have a `startpos` parameter.

Comment: Tried it using re module of python, but does not seem to work. Code{for i in re.finditer(r"(?<=XYZ)((?:ABC)+)","Some text followed by XYZ followed by multiple ABC, more ABC, more ABC").}. Would Python be having a different notation? I would check it out. Thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: You mean that in a string like `"Some ABC ABC text followed by XYZ followed by multiple ABC, more ABC, more ABC"` it should return to you only the last three `ABC` instances?

Comment: Yes, only those ABC's following the XYZ - the last three.

Answer (score 0):

There is a nifty Counter object in collections which may be of help. A Counter object is a dictionary with the keys being the individual items, and the values the counts. Example:

```
Counter('hello there hello'.split()) # {'hello':2, 'there', 1}
```

Since we want to count words, we must split the phrase wherever we see whitespace. This is the default behavior of the split method. Here is an example script which uses Counter. The lower half could be adapted into a function if required.

```
from collections import Counter

def count_frequency(phrase):
    """ Return a dictionary with {word: num_of_occurences} """
    counts = Counter(phrase.split())
    return counts

def replace_word(target_word, replacement, phrase):
    """ Replaces *word* with *replacement* in string *phrase* """
    phrase = phrase.split()

    for count, word in enumerate(phrase):
        if word == target_word:
            phrase[count] = replacement

    return ''.join(phrase)

phrase = "hello there hello hello"
word_counts = count_frequency(phrase)
new_phrase = ''
replacement = 'replaced'

for word in word_counts:
    if word_counts[word] > 2:
        phrase = phrase.replace(word, replacement)

print(phrase)
```